# Kafka Connect: run JAR file without Connect cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Is it possible to run Kafka Connect plugin as a regular JAR file without the Connect cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; it is not. Plugins are not executable.

Kafka Connect requires multiple JAR files for the API and the runtime itself. All JARs are put together on the classpath when you run `connect-standalone` or `connect-distributed`

Plugins are scanned while the server is starting.